# What format does the apple notes sqlite db date use?

Tags: iphone, ios, notes.app, sqlite

I want to extract the note texts and modification dates from an sqlite notes database extracted from an iOS device backup. But I can't figure out how to convert the date format to a readable date string.

## How I got the data

I found out which file had the note data from [this page](http://tomscoding.tumblr.com/post/28190447430/import-old-notes-from-iphone-into-mac-mountain).

Relevant portion:

```
Step 1. Find the Backup File in ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/fea….627
        something like : ca3b….39c
       If you have trouble seeing Library folder 
       defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles Yes
Step 2. Copy file and rename as notes.sqlite
```

## What I've tried so far

I've opened the file up and confirmed it has the expected note body text inside it. The body text is inside a table called `ZNOTEBODY`. Another table called `ZNOTE` has a a `ZBODY`column which appears to contain indices into the `ZNOTEBODY` table, and a `ZMODIFICATIONDATE` column. Here is the crux of the matter: The `ZMODIFICATIONDATE` column has a listed type of `TIMESTAMP` and it contains floating point numbers.

I looked at the [sqlite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and found this:

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

So I tried using the built-in `datetime` function with a simple `SELECT datetime(ZMODIFICATIONDATE) FROM ZNOTE;` but that produced nonsense values like `1171380-13689427-18 21:08:40` for an entry I know corresponds to 2014-08-12. The stored value in question was `429559087.38102`.

So, does anyone know what format is being used here? Or, more importantly how to convert it to a readable date?

The following stored dates all correspond to (different points on) 2014-08-11, in order of earliest to latest.

- `429435093.400244`
- `429446655.298724`
- `429447111.140259`
- `429460783.273032`
- `429464301.184442`

(I wasn't sure where to post this, but since it seems like it might be Apple specific, this seemed like the best spot.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25865638/4751173) on Stack Overflow, it's a Unix timestamp adjusted by 31 years. This is typical of CoreData, Apple's ORM framework. The following would work:

```
select datetime(zmodificationdate,'unixepoch','31 years') from znote
```

Comment: For others coming here looking for tips on interpreting dates stored in sqlite by iOS apps: some apps (stupidly) save timestamps as local time rather than UTC; in that case you need to add a `'localtime'` parameter to that `datetime` call, e.g. `datetime(foo, 'unixepoch', '31 years', 'localtime')` - particularly tricky for UK users (say) where localtime == UTC for half the year but not the other half!